# Regarding diagonalizability

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

Let $X$, $Y$ and $H$ be $n \times n$ matrices such that $XY-YX=H$, $XH-HX=-2X$ and $YH-HY=2Y$. Using only this data can we prove that $H$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: Where does this question come from, please?

Comment: Basically it comes from sl(2, C) representation. But I want to know whether it can be proved  without using lie algebra theorems?